# if button is in disabled condition then its color should lightgray and if button is enable state then color should green

Tags: vue.js

here I have written vue.js code for form. And here the functionality is while all the form fields is filled then I want to enable a button and if any of the fields are required then the button should disable and this function is working is fine. But the issue is i want to change the color like if button is disable then the color should lightgray and if the button is enable the button color should green. Please help me to solve the issue.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="form">
    <input type="text" v-model='name'/>
    
    <input type="text" v-model='fname'/>
    
    <input type="text" v-model='phn'/>
    <button :disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
  </div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#form',
  data: {
    name: '',
    fname: '',
    phn: ''

  },
  methods: {},
  computed: {
    disabled(){
      return !this.name || !this.fname || !this.phn;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Use css. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_disabled.asp . You could have searched a little online and found the answer yourself, me thinks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved without JavaScript by using CSS. Like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/3xbdmghz/

HTML

```
<button disabled>Hello</button>
<button>World</button>
```

CSS

```
button {
  background: #00ff00;
}    
button:disabled {
  background: #cccccc;
}
```

If you only want this formatting to apply to this one button, you could give it a class and then refer to that in the CSS. In this example the first two buttons will get the formatting, but the last two won't:

https://jsfiddle.net/8zo9uha2/

HTML

```
<button class="formatted" disabled>Hello</button>
<button class="formatted">World</button>
<br/>
<button disabled>Hello</button>
<button >World</button>
```

CSS

```
.formatted {
  background: #00ff00;
}
.formatted:disabled {
  background: #cccccc;
}
```